# Issue using WPF MediaElement with HD (H.264, 720P) Video

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

I am using media element to render video in WPF. All videos are working fine except H.264 videos. They have some stuttering problem while they are rendered on screen. My machine configuration is much more than the recommended requirement to play for this video. Another surprising fact is that the video renders perfectly fine when I play this in Window Media Player or any other player.
Any solution or any alternative to MediaElement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF does not support H.264 videos

Comment: WPF's `MediaElement` plays H.264 videos fine for me on Windows 7, but not XP.

Comment: H.264 videos play perfectly fine with me too... and I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: It works with Windows 7 because MediaElement hooks into MediaFoundation which supports these codecs.  You might be able to get it to work on XP if you install ffdshow/CoreAVC.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my MediaUriElement from my open source project here:  http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com

It has better media compatibility than MediaElement, but if it's a decoder filter problem or a performance problem, my project won't be able to help.  What h264 codec are you using.  You may want to try out ffdshow from http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/.

-Jer