# Pink lines/distortion in MediaUriElement (from WPFMediaKit) for HD video

Tags: wpf, media-player, mediaelement, distortion, wpf-mediakit

I have a media player in WPF that was previously using the `MediaElement` control to show video. But on XP it did not show some HD videos. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490791/issue-using-wpf-mediaelement-with-hd-h-264-720p-video) thread's advice I started using the WPFMediaKit library's `MediaUriElement` instead. Now I can get the HD videos to play, but they have pink lines/distortion going across the top:

[image]

That's the top 1/5 of the screen. The distortion will flash at the top for a second, then go away. This happens every couple of seconds. The rest of the video plays fine.
The video plays fine if I open it in Windows Media Player.

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Comment: Check your codecs, see https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit/wiki/Codecs and check your video using some DirectShow player, like MPC-HC player (included in the K-Lite codecs).